# jquery find not getting the invalid elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this div inside my page;

```
<div class="workspace" id="workspace">
    <div data-ng-repeat="node in controller.Nodes" on-last-repeat=on-last-repeat>
    </div>
</div>
```

On my typescript code, I have this to check if there are required fields that are not set.

```
if ($('#workspace').find('.ng-invalid').length != 0)
```

This is not working. The length is always 0. I also tried the following below but no luck:

```
if ($('#workspace').find('.has-error.form-control').length != 0)
if ($('#workspace').find('.invalid').length != 0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Stop using jQuery. Use Angular, think Angular.

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but still a useful tip: `$('#workspace').find('.ng-invalid')` can be simplified to `$('#workspace .ng-invalid')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

child element do not have class attribute. You can rather use `has attribute selector`:

```
if ($('#workspace').find('[data-ng-repeat]').length != 0)
```

Comment: Great. It is returning the proper length but how can I find the ones with invalid class only?

Comment: @GeraldGonzales: there are no elements with class in shared html. please share the html that has class name.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it is because you run the JQuery part before the document is completely ready?

I have an example like this:

```
if ($('#workspace .ng-invalid').length != 0) {
  console.log('found in FIRST');
}

// on document.ready
$(function() {
  if ($('#workspace .ng-invalid').length != 0) {
    console.log('found in SECOND');
  }
});
```

and only the second triggers.

To iterate over all invalid elements with JQuery use `each(index, object)`:

```
$(function() {
  $('#workspace .ng-invalid').each( function (index, object) {
    console.log(object);
  });
});
```